# How to set a default background color for a page when the background is transparent

Tags: html, css

I have page in which I have set the background as completely transparent using:

```
body {
  background:none transparent!important;
}
```

This works as intended I am displaying this page in a transparent iframe on a different website and I want to see the website background through the page.

However if I access the page directly the background shows as white (its got to be something right?)

**Is this a hardcoded browser thing or is there a way I can set this to black?**

Website code:

```
<div class="page-background ">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Website menu here</span>
      <span><a href="index.html">Book</a></span>
      <span><a href="about.html">About</a></span>
      <span><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:4500" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you access directly, your `body` has its parent as `html` which has background as white. This is the reason you see the white background. If you want to see black, you need to set your `html` to black background

Answer (score 2):

When you access directly, your `body` has its parent as `html` which has background as white. This is the reason you see the white background. If you want to see black, you need to set your `html` to black background

```css
html {
  background: #000;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.body.style.background = 'transparent';">
  Make Transparent
</button>
```

Comment: I actually tried this.  Unfortunately this does not work for my case.  I need to "see through"  the html and iframe to the website background the iframe is hosted in.
I will edit my question to add the iframe code.

Comment: you will have to handle this conditionally based on if you directly access it or via an iframe.

Comment: Yes that could be a way to do it.  I could pass a parameter in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `background-color:initial;` has worked for me, i hope it does yours

Answer (score 0):

Just create these three files and provide the image link in background-image attribute then second file name should be test2.html and third file name shoud be test3.html. Then run the first file and click on book option.

```html
<html>
<body style="background-image:url('wallpaper2you_462082.jpg');background-size:cover">
<div class="page-background ">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Website menu here</span>
      <span><a href="test2.html" target="iframe">Book</a></span>
      <span><a href="about.html">About</a></span>
      <span><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></span>
    </div>
    <iframe src="test3.html" allowtransparency="true" name="iframe"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<body style='color:white'>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>How are you?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<body style='color:red'>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>How are you?</p>
<p>Tell me about yourself.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You are at the same point I am.  What I want from there is that if you go direct (not through the iframe) to test2.html or test3.html the background is not white but black.